TextPad slow opening files in some cases
I have been using TextPad 7 for years with no issues but I decided to upgrade to version 9 to get better UTF-16 support. Now both version 9 and version 7 are slow opening files in some cases no matter which I reinstall.
At this moment I just have Notepad as the app associated with .txt files because TextPad is so slow when I double-click on a file with TextPad as the associated app. If I right-click and choose "Open with TextPad" it opens fast. If I right-click and choose "Open with" and then TextPad it is slow. It just spins for a while. If I open a file through a shortcut on OneDrive it doesn't do anything and the file shows syncing status. I see similar behavior on c:\temp which isn't in OneDrive.
It's a bummer because I have used TextPad 7 all this time and I don't even know how to go back to it. Thanks for any ideas/help.

If you're seeing different behaviors, look at the registry, specifically HKCR.txt and look through there for the different arguments that may be opening text files. Another thing to do is use Process Explorer (by Microsoft), open a file using both methods, and look at the process arguments in each case. Noting the differences may indicate what, specifically, the problem is, and probably help indicate WHAT needs to change in order to fix this.

This was helpful. I was able to understand that TextPad was using DDE to get the name of the file and that seems to be the problem. I came up with a hack to get around it by associating a .bat file with the .txt type so it will just run textpad.exe passing the file name on the command line.
